# Colon (:) in Python list index

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I see `:` used in list indices especially when it's associated with function calls.

Python 2.7 documentation suggests that `lists.append` translates to `a[len(a):] = [x]`. Why does one need to suffix `len(a)` with a colon?

I understand that `:` is used to identify keys in dictionary.

Comment: Where do I get python 4.7? Me wants! In 2.7, [The Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) covers your question quite nicely.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

`:` is the delimiter of the slice syntax to 'slice out' sub-parts in sequences , `[start:end]`

```
[1:5] is equivalent to "from 1 to 5" (5 not included)
[1:] is equivalent to "1 to end"
[len(a):] is equivalent to "from length of a to end"
```

Watch https://youtu.be/tKTZoB2Vjuk?t=41m40s at around 40:00 he starts explaining that.

Works with tuples and strings, too.

Comment: Remember that [1:5] starts with the object at index 1, and the object at index 5 is not included.  You can also make a soft copy of a list with [:]

Comment: Because it's not actually that easy to Google punctuation like ':', I particularly appreciated finding your answer and found it helpful. Even using something like symbolhound, its so commonly used that I was afraid I wouldn't be able to find an answer quickly.

Comment: Does not work with dictionaries.  applying d[:5] is the eqivalent of d.__getitem__(slice(0, 5, None)).  A slice is not hashable.

Comment: Also you can have step in there: `[start:end:step]`, which is why `[::-1]` reverses with normal start and end, but backwards step.

Comment: Your explanation of ":" meaning "to end" is what really allowed me to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Your last example needs more explanation. "from length of a to end". Shouldn't this always return an empty array? There's nothing at "length of a". The last index of a should be len(a) - 1, right?

Comment: Why am I getting `invalid syntax` when I write `[1:5]` in python interpreter?

Comment: @TomCharlesZhang these are operators operating on an iterable. If you just `[1:5]` Python doesn't understand what you're operating on. It has to be something like `"Hello World"[1:5]` for example, or `['a','b','c','d', 'e','f','g'][1:5]`

Answer (score 22):

slicing operator. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings and scroll down a bit

Answer (score 15):

`a[len(a):]`  - This gets you the length of a to the end. It selects a range. If you reverse    `a[:len(a)]`  it will get you the beginning to whatever is `len(a)`.

Comment: Why wold you want to get a subarray starting at the length of the array (a[len(a):])? Shouldn't this just return an empty subarray always since there are no elements after index len(a) - 1?

Comment: @AjaxLeung empty slices are useful because you can assign to them:

a = list(range(0,10)) 
print('a\t', a)                    # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print('slice\t', a[3:3])        # []
a[3:3] =  [10,10,10]
print('new a\t', a)            # [0, 1, 2, 10, 10, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]