# Removing unwanted elements in between wanted elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that can be simplified to something like this:

```
a=[nan, 2, 1, 1, nan, nan, 3, nan, nan, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 7, nan, nan, nan, 3, 2, nan, 2]
```

I would like to keep the elements `3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 7` the `nan` elements don't bother me because they don't show up in the graphic, but I would like to filter the rest of the values.

Criteria: Longest sequence without a nan

Comment: What **exactly** is the criteria for the numbers you want to keep?

Comment: The criteria would be something along the lines of the longest sequence without an interruption (nan)

Comment: "Something along the lines"?  If you know exactly what you want, edit that specification into your question.  If you don't know what you want, you're not ready to ask on SO yet.

Comment: Yes, I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substantially edited since the question is clarified.

To get the longest sequence you can use [**`groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [**`max`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from math import isnan

>>> nan = float('NaN')

>>> a = [nan, 2, 1, 1, nan, nan, 3, nan, nan, 3, 4, 7, 8,
...      9, 8, 7, 7, nan, nan, nan, 3, 2, nan, 2]

>>> max((list(group) for key, group in groupby(a, key=isnan)), key=len)
[3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 7]
```

Comment: This is wrong. NaN compares not equal with all elements as part of the IEEE specification.

'float('nan') == float('nan')` -> False
'float('nan') != float('nan') -> True

Comment: @EfronLicht I wasn't think `nan` was the same as `NaN`. I should have clarified before answering.

Comment: I would like to keep only the sequence '3, 4, 7, 8,9, 8, 7, 7' not the other values

Comment: @RicardoFumachi Why not the other values?

Comment: @PeterWood the question is ambiguous. I'm making an (educated) guess too.

Comment: Respectfully, I have trouble believing that transcript is real.  That's not how `groupby` works.

Comment: I see, I was not familiar with the groupby function, it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent place for a list comprehension.

The syntax is as follows: `[x for x in my_list if condition()]`

So, assuming your criteria are  `x is nan or x>=3`:

```
from math import isnan
filtered_list = [x for x in my_list if isnan(x) or x >=3]
```

Note that nan behaves unusually: for any variable `v`, `(nan==v)==False .`
Use `math.isnan` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could just try

```
     a = a[9:-7]
```

after your current code...

See [Colon (:) in Python list index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012340/colon-in-python-list-index) for explanation

Comment: Yes, but I would like a way to determine the starting and ending point without having to actually look at the array. by playing with the nans maybe?

Comment: What is the criteria? The longest sequence without `nan`?

Comment: If you need an automated solution yes, but you need to be more specific with your question... how do you choose the elements? Position? Relative position to others (I.e. Nan elements)?

Comment: Yes, the criteria is as Peter said the longest sequence without a nan