# I want to implement python list in cpp, but stuck at overloading subscript operator [ ] and comma ,

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, slice, comma-operator, subscript-operator

I want to implement puthon list in cpp, bug do not fin a way to implement pyton's slice operator, e.g.:

```
list[3:7]   // sublist including item 3 included to item 7 excluded
```

As colon is not an operator in cpp, we cannot overload it. So I changed my implementation to use an overloadable comma, e.g. `list[3,7]`.  I think I first need to overload comma operator and then overload `[ ]` operator

But I am getting error while overloading `[ ]` with 2 integers:

```
Error is : operator[](int, int) must have exactly one argument
```

Please help me solve the issue.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot get any of the syntaxes. You are correct that operator `:` cannot be overloaded, but to overload on `,` operator you would need a class object (or enum) - you cannot provide operator overloads for primitive types like ints. If you can live with `list(3, 7)` or `list[{3, 7}]`, this could be done.

Comment: The closest you can come to what you want is overloading `operator()`

Comment: This is not easy... the only option is using slices in rangev3

Comment: Indeed,  the duplicate is not appropriate: it's not about a 2D index but about [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4012340/3723423), which is also dificult because lower or upper operand could be missing.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard imposes restrictions on `operator[]`:

> **[over.sub]:** `operator[]` shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter. It implements the subscripting syntax
>
> (...) a subscripting expression `x[y]` is interpreted as `x.operator[](y)` (...)

But the single argument doesn't need to be a scalar. For example:

```
struct mylist {
    vector<int> oops { 3,5, 7, 9}; 
    int& operator[] (size_t i) { 
        cout << "indexing overload"<<endl; 
        return oops[i]; 
    }
    mylist operator[] (pair<int, int>p) { 
        cout << "slicing overload from "<<p.first<<" to "<<p.second<<endl; 
        return mylist();    // just for proof of concept  
    }
};
```

You can then use this list as explected:

```
mylist l; 
cout<< l[2] <<endl;  // (1) traditional indexing 
l[make_pair(3,5)];   // (2) will invoke the slice version 
l[{4,8}];            // (3) slice version as well
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/7IiFsf)

However, C++ is not python, so the readers of your code will be very confused by the syntax of (2) and (3).  Moreover, I'm not a python expert but I understand that [slice operator](https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-list-slicing/) can be more tricky than that, since there could be start, stop and step and any of those components can be missing.

So I'd recommend not to use a pair as an argument,  but create your own slice operator parameters.  You could then work on different constructors and default parameters. It could then look like:

```
l[myslice(3, 5)];     // myslice is a class 
l[myslice(3, 4, 2)]; 
l[mysliceto(5)];      // mysliceto could be a function returning a myslice
                      // that is constructed using a default value for start
```

But since this would still be quite an unusual indexing scheme, with a view to the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment),  I'd strongly recommend to go for the C++ usual practice and simply define the right member functions, e.g. `

```
l.slice(3,5);
```

This will be self-documenting, without surprise, and easily digested, since it is close to well known semantics of [`string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)